# Converting multiple href links to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I am doing updates on an online webcart and I am trying to control the options available. One way to remove an item is to put a link:

```
<a class="jcart-remove" href="?jcartRemove=item1">REMOVE</a>
```

How do I add this to a submit button? Ideally I would love to POST information on submit and then remove items at the same time. I am assuming that this method since it calls up a specific URL can't be used in a string.

Ideally I would love for multiple items to be able to be removed with a single click.

```
<a class="jcart-remove" href="?jcartRemove=item1">REMOVE</a>
<a class="jcart-remove" href="?jcartRemove=item2">REMOVE</a>
<a class="jcart-remove" href="?jcartRemove=item3">REMOVE</a>
```

Can these be gathered together as an "Onclick" function?

Answer (score 0):

You could use jquery..

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
  $(".jcart-remove").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      this.remove();
  });
});
```

You would then have to update the data to make sure that it does not show back up on the client side.